# Minecraft worlds

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

How can I add a other world to my minecraft server and still keep my worlds? I tried to add a world to FileZilla. The world name was called "Wild". I then went to console and changed the world name to "Wild" then restart. When I came back all the worlds were gone.

Comment: You could always use a Bukkit server and use something like MultiVerse to manage worlds.

Answer (score 1):

In your server directory, you have all your worlds saved. By default, your world is called just `world`. In the `server.properties` file, you can change the world name by editing the value of `level-name`. When you then restart the server, it should generate a new world after the name. When you want to come back to the old world, just change the `level-name` value back to the name. You can have as many worlds as you want.